# check user grant specific permission after opening setting

Tags: android, permissions, fragment, runtime-permissions

when user checked **Don't ask again** option and pressed DENY, i update view by showing a button to whenever again wants to change permission setting don't need to open setting and change permission and by clicking on button setting will open.

i used below code to open setting:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", mContext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), null);
        intent.setData(uri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

but in **onActivityResult** even user grant or not result code is 0 and i can't understand to start camera or not in my Fragment.

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA)
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
                startCamera();
            else {
                changeUiToNotGrantedView();
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When user returns from settings, you should just check again if permission is now granted or not with 
`requestPermissions( arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA), YOUR_REQUEST_CODE)`.

If user granted camera permission in settings, you will know in `onRequestPermissionsResult(...)` and based on that you can start camera or not.

Comment: it works, but i don't understand why result code is always 0. ِDoes it related to how using `startActivityForResult(intent, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA)` to get `Activity.RESULT_OK`?

Comment: Its just not meant to work that way as far as my research goes. There is no result and you can use startyActivity() instead of startActivityForResult().

Comment: startActivityForResult() can help you detect that user have came back from settings to your app, so you can call checkSelfPermission(...) and determine whether or not user has granted permissions in settings.

Comment: thank you, using `checkSelfPermissio()` in `onActivityResult` worked for me.